# How can I run wget through Octave

Tags: url, download, octave, wget

I've seen examples of wget being ran through matlab, and I wondered if there's any way to do the same thing through Octave. I already tried the functions in Octave but they're not customizable enough that they work for the downloads I need. Thanks in advance!

Edit: I didn't know about the `system()` function, should work with that. Thanks Vicky :)

Comment: Hi Feva, welcome to SO! You can use the [`system()`](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/system.html) function to run arbitrary shell commands, including `wget ...` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As another commenter said, you can use `system()` to run arbitrary shell commands.

However, if your intention is simply to add a 'downloading' function inside an octave script, then you can use octave's `urlread` command for that instead. This reads a website, and returns its source code as a string.

This might be particularly preferred if the only reason you're downloading a file through octave in the first place is to then open it from within octave and read its contents.

There is also `webread`. Have a look at their documentation to compare the two.